# Union in GADT type variable

Tags: haskell, gadt

I have a GADT constructor representing the same idea, but I need two of them because the type is flexible depending on context. See this contrived example:

```
data A
data B
data C

data Thing a where
  AFoo :: String -> Thing A
  Bar  :: Float -> Thing A
  BFoo :: String -> Thing B
  Baz  :: Int -> Thing B
  Bah  :: Char -> Thing C
```

`AFoo` and `BFoo` represent the same underlying data concept: some data with a string. But in this context, it's more than that. Ideally `AFoo` and `BFoo` would be merged into `Foo`, because they represent exactly the same thing, but I need one that types like `Thing A` and one that types like `Thing B`. As mentioned before, some contexts in which a `Foo` can be used require a `Thing A` and some require a `Thing B`, so to satisfy the type system one constructor needs to exist for each.

I could of course write a function that "casts" to the desired type by switching the constructor if needed:

```
fooAsThingA :: Thing a -> Maybe (Thing A)
fooAsThingA t@(AFoo _) = Just t
fooAsThingA (BFoo s) = Just $ AFoo s
fooAsThingA _ = Nothing
```

(And similarly for `fooAsThingB`)

But this is ugly, because it requires a `Maybe` that I have to propagate because not all `Thing B`s can become `Thing A`s (in fact, only `BFoo` can).

Ideally, I'd like to write:

```
data A
data B
data C

data Thing a where
  Foo :: String -> Thing ??
  Bar :: Float -> Thing A
  Baz :: Int -> Thing B
  Bah :: Char -> Thing C
```

But I'm unclear on what I'd put in place of the `??`. Presumably it's some way of representing the union of `A` and `B` (and perhaps this requires changing the types of the other constructors for this GADT, but that's fine).

Just to be clear, if the above were valid, I'd expect given the following functions:

```
processThingA :: Thing A -> String
processThingB :: Thing B -> Int
processThingC :: Thing C -> Float
```

Then, I'd be able to do all of the following:

```
processThingA $ Foo "Hello"
processThingB $ Foo "World"

processThingA $ Bar 3.14
processThingB $ Baz 42

processThingC $ Bah '\n'
```

tl;dr In the first snippet, is it possible to merge `AFoo` and `BFoo` into a `Foo` that types as both `Thing A` and `Thing B`?

**edit:** Note: there are other `EmptyDataDecls` than `A` and `B` that I use for `Thing a`. I added `C` as an example.

Comment: What about `data Thing a where Foo :: String -> Thing a ...`? Or you could use `DataKinds` to restrict it a bit: `data ThingType = A | B; data Thing (a :: ThingType) where Foo :: String -> Thing a ...`. Do those fit with your use case?

Comment: @DavidYoung Ohh, that's an interesting solution. I haven't played around much with `DataKinds`. I do have other types (updated question to add a `Thing C`) which I don't want to part of this "union," so I don't think the first would work. But if I did `data AOrB = A | B; data C` would there be a way with `DataKinds` to restrict only the type for the `Foo` constructor?

Comment: You can use `Foo :: String -> AorB t -> Thing t` where `AorB t` is a suitable GADT, only populated by `JustA :: AorB A` and `Just B :: AorB B`. It's not terribly convenient, and has some memory overhead, but it could work well enough. You could even use a type class to keep that witness "implicit", in principle. The overhead is still there, but one does not have to pass it explicitly.

Comment: @chi Thanks! So then for example, I'd have to do `Bar :: Float -> Thing JustA`? And for `Bah`, I'd keep the `data C` and have it be `Bah :: Char -> Thing C`? I'm not too bothered by the memory overhead, but I am a little irked that this would require pattern matching on an additional useless value. Can you expand on how this can be done with type classes? It's not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: @chi Also, having tried this out, it looks like this just pushes the problem into the `AorB` value. How do I instantiate a `Foo`? `Foo "abc" JustA` can only be used in `Thing (AorB A)` contexts. It seems like I'd still need a "runtime cast"-like thing to change `Foo "abc" JustA` into a `Foo "abc" JustB` to be able to pass it into a function expecting `Thing (AorB B)` (and this has the aforementioned problem of having too broad of a type `Thing a -> Thing (AorB A)` which requires a `Maybe`). Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @chi On second though, I guess you can do `Foo "abc" undefined`, but that feels dirty. The possibility of accidentally forcing the undefined value is there. Would doing this with type classes prevent this?

Comment: No, `Bar` is still `Float -> Thing A`. There is no `Thing AorB` type in this approach. If you need that you need yet another wrapper type, or a typeclass. E.g. suppose we have `class IsAorB t where proof :: AorB t`. Then we can use `Foo :: IsAorB t => String -> Thing t`. If you want a function consuming only `Foo`s. You can write `func :: forall t. IsAorB t => Thing t -> ... ; func x = case proof @ t where JustA -> ... ; JustB -> ...` or something similar. I'm not claiming that this is an ideal approach. I do not have a very neat and simple solution to this problem.

Comment: Ah indeed that does work! Although it feels a bit forced having to do that typeclass dance, this does have the benefit that you can work with the constructors and GADT as if it were declared in the usual manner (without this trickery). This is sufficient for my use case. If you'd like to write this up, I'll gladly mark as solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is as follows, even I do not consider it elegant.

We first define a GADT and a type class for being "A or B":

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GADTs, EmptyCase,
             ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}

data Sort = A | B | C | D

data AorB (s :: Sort) where
  IsA :: AorB 'A
  IsB :: AorB 'B

class IsAorB (s :: Sort) where
  aorb :: AorB s

instance IsAorB 'A where aorb = IsA
instance IsAorB 'B where aorb = IsB
```

Then we exploit our type class in our type. This will cause `Foo` to require some more space, since it needs to store the typeclass dictionary at runtime. It is a small amount of overhead, but it is still unfortunate. On the other hand, this will also make it possible to discern, at runtime, whether the `s` used in `Foo` is actually `A` or `B`.

```
data Thing (s :: Sort) where
  Foo :: IsAorB s => String -> Thing s 
  Bar :: Float -> Thing 'A
  Baz :: Int -> Thing 'B
  Bah :: Char -> Thing 'C
```

Some tests:

```
processThingA :: Thing 'A -> String
processThingA (Foo x) = x
processThingA (Bar x) = show x

processThingB :: Thing 'B -> Int
processThingB (Foo _) = 0
processThingB (Baz i) = i
```

A main downside is that we need to convince the exhaustiveness checker that our pattern matching is OK.

```
-- This unfortunately will give a spurious warning
processThingC :: Thing 'C -> Float
processThingC (Bah _) = 42.2
-- To silence the warning we need to prove that this is indeed impossible
processThingC (Foo _) = case aorb :: AorB 'C of {}

processThingAorB :: forall s. IsAorB s => Thing s -> String
processThingAorB (Foo x) = x
processThingAorB (Bar x) = "Bar " ++ show x
processThingAorB (Baz x) = "Baz " ++ show x
-- Again, to silence the warnings
processThingAorB (Bah _) = case aorb :: AorB 'C of {}

test :: ()
test = ()
  where
  _ = processThingA $ Foo "Hello"
  _ = processThingB $ Foo "World"
  _ = processThingA $ Bar 3.14
  _ = processThingB $ Baz 42
  _ = processThingC $ Bah '\n'
```

This technique does not scale very well. We need a custom GADT and typeclass for any constructor of `Thing` which can generate any tag in some "union". This can still be OK. To check exhaustiveness, we would need to exploit all these classes.

I think this should require a linear amount of boilerplate, but it still significant.

Perhaps using singletons is simpler, in the general case, to store the value of `s` in the constructor `Foo`, and avoid all the custom GADTs and typeclasses.